# Disabling and enabling html tag to prevent multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery structure:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () {   
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    // API call1
    // API call2
    // API call3
    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
}
```

I have done this disabling and enabling to prevent user from clicking multiple times which is causing multiple issues.

The problem with this is API calls are Asynchronous and I don't want to make them Synchronous.

But making them Async would execute Line5 before API calls which i dont want. Making it enabled on each APIs success and error is also too much of an effort.

Any other better suggestion to make sure line 5 executes after completion of 2,3,4?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this:

```
$.when(api1, api2, api3).done(function(){});
```

Comment: This would work with api1, api2, api3 being any general function too? Just i need to separate them with comma?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the deferred objects returned by the AJAX calls in an array and then `apply` that to `$.when` to enable the button once all the requests have completed. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () {   
    var $el = $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    var requests = [];
    requests.push(request1);
    requests.push(request2);
    requests.push(request3);

    $.when.apply(requests).done(function() {
        $el.prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.when.apply(requests).done(function() {  $el.prop("disabled", false);..`

Comment: I think `$el.prop("disabled", false);` should be applied after **all** requests are done.

Comment: That is what is happening.